# How to convert a Python pandas into a Julia DataFrame (using PyJulia) and back to Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, julia, julia-dataframe

I want to use `PyJulia` to speed up some part of the code

```
import numpy as np
import julia
import pandas as pd
import random
from julia import Base
from julia import Main
from julia import DataFrames

n = 100000
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,n):
    num = random.randint(1,100)
    randomlist.append(num)

data = {
    'Score': list(randomlist),
        'ScoreBin': list(np.zeros(n))
           }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Score', 'ScoreBin'])
Main.dfj = df

Main.eval(""" 
for i = 1:10
    #println(i)
    if dfj.Score[i] >= 10
        println(dfj.Score[i])
    end
end
"""
)
```

However I get the following error Message:

```
JuliaError: Exception 'TypeError: non-boolean (PyObject) used in boolean context' occurred while calling julia code:
```

Moreover the following command:

```
Main.eval(""" 
println(dfj.Score[1])
"""
)
```

gives the output (which appears not to be a Julia DataFrame):

```
PyObject 84
```

Is there a way to convert a pandas DataFrame into a Julia DataFrame?

**Edit 1**

Thanks to the answer of @PrzemyslawSzufel, the following code now works:

```
import numpy as np
import julia
import pandas as pd
import random
import copy
from julia import Base
from julia import Main
from julia import DataFrames
from julia import Pandas
#julia.install(DataFrame)
%load_ext julia.magic

n = 100000
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,n):
    num = random.randint(1,100)
    randomlist.append(num)

data = {
    'Score': list(randomlist),
        'ScoreBin': list(np.zeros(n))
           }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Score', 'ScoreBin'])
Main.df = df;

Main.eval("""
dfj = df |> Pandas.DataFrame|> DataFrames.DataFrame;
""")
```

However, although I put a `;` at the end of the line, I always get a printed output from dfj which is unwanted and long (100000 rows) and takes around a second. Is there way to avoid the printed output?

Moreover, if I now modify the dataframe in Julia (which is way faster than doing that in python and the goal of the whole question) and want it to convert it back to a python pandas, I also get an error

```
Main.eval(""" 
for i = 1:length(dfj[:, :Score])
    if dfj[i, :Score] > 50
        dfj[i, :ScoreBin] = 1 
    end
end
"""
)

dfjpy = pd.DataFrame(Main.dfj)
dfjpy


RuntimeError: Julia exception: MethodError: no method matching iterate(::DataFrames.DataFrame)
Closest candidates are:
  iterate(!Matched::Core.SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:568
  iterate(!Matched::Core.SimpleVector, !Matched::Any) at essentials.jl:568
  iterate(!Matched::ExponentialBackOff) at error.jl:199
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] jlwrap_iterator(::DataFrames.DataFrame) at /Users/mymac/.julia/packages/PyCall/zqDXB/src/pyiterator.jl:144
 [2] pyjlwrap_getiter(::Ptr{PyCall.PyObject_struct}) at /Users/mymac/.julia/packages/PyCall/zqDXB/src/pyiterator.jl:125
```

By the way the command `type(dfjpy)` gives `PyCall.jlwrap` as output

**Edit 2**

In order to convert a julia Dataframe to Python Pandas, you have to first convert it to a Julia Pandas. Is is the latest working code

```
n = 100000
randomlist = []
for i in range(0,n):
    num = random.randint(1,100)
    randomlist.append(num)

data = {
    'Score': list(randomlist),
        'ScoreBin': list(np.zeros(n))
           }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Score', 'ScoreBin'])
Main.df = df;

Main.eval("""
dfj = df |> Pandas.DataFrame|> DataFrames.DataFrame;

for i = 1:length(dfj[:, :Score])
    if dfj[i, :Score] > 50
        dfj[i, :ScoreBin] = 1 
    end
end

dfjp = dfj |> Pandas.DataFrame;
"""
)

dfjpy = Main.dfjp
dfjpy
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have `Pandas.jl` installed. This library will process your Python pandas data frame for sanity with Julia and than you can convert it to `DataFrames.jl`.

Here is the Julia code (assumes that `dfj` is your Python variable):

```
import DataFrames
import Pandas
juliandf = dfj |> Pandas.DataFrame |> DataFrames.DataFrame;
```

Note that the last line can be also written as:

```
C= DataFrames.DataFrame(Pandas.DataFrame(dfj));
```

To convert back `Pandas.DataFrame(juliandf)` should work.

Comment: Many thanks to your answer @PrzemyslawSzufel. The code works (I edited the question). However, is there a way of avoiding the printed output for the line juliandf = dfj |> Pandas.DataFrame |> DataFrames.DataFrame? And how is it possible to convert a Julia DataFrames back to a Python pandas?

Comment: Well, in the latest working code, both problems seems to have resolved